# How can I create a window that displays glpoints using freeglut?

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glut

My question is quite simple, I need to initialize a window and use it to display pixels moving around and touching each other (I'm doing a DLA application). I need this to be done purely in GLUT as it needs to be cross platform. I'm not going to be displaying any 3D objects btw. Oh also I'm programming it in c++

Comment: Why the "purely in GLUT" requirement? GLUT is outdated. Some lightweight libraries for that purpose which are held more up-to-date are GLFW and SDL. Is this acceptable?

Comment: When I was trying out GLUT, I remember there was an easy guide to do that. I think I was reading the Red Book (the OpenGL Programming Guide... I think). Since the whole point of GLUT is just to do simple stuff like this really easily, I think it should be really easy to find the info you want on Google.

Comment: I just realised it's outdated and may change to something slightly more up-to date.
@genpfault DLA: Diffusion limited aggregation. It's used to model different patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both any edition of the [Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552628), the [Superbible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712617) (4th ed. or older), OpenGL-centric textbooks (like [Hill, *et. al.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131496700)), and every outdated tutorial (particularly [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/)) will cover all of this, if the [GLUT manual](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html) is inadequate.

Comment: The problem I found with NeHe is he would usually use windows.h which I cannot use on Linux.

Comment: ＠yousefcisco: Look at the bottom of the NeHe Tutorials http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01
You can download there the source code for Linux as well!